# Vue trying to set boostrap theme seems to not be working

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, vue.js, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

I am trying to set bootstrap theme for fullcalendar in vue, but it is giving me a weird theme(picture provided at the end)

I have followed the documentation instructions and even used the vue example to isolated the updates, (codesandbox provided at the end)

Documentation says to add themeSystem='bootstrap' arg. import and add plugin. import stylesheet.

Am i doing something wrong or missing something?

My code is just a tiny bit different than the example: provided here

```
  <Container class="wpc-userscheduledetailviewcontent">
    <v-flex>
      <div id="calendar">
        <FullCalendar ref="fullCalendar"
                      defaultView="dayGridMonth"
                      themeSystem="bootstrap"
                      :plugins="calendarPlugins"
                      :header="calendarHeader"
                      :selectable="true"
                      @select="onSelectDay"></FullCalendar>
      </div>
    </v-flex>
  </Container>
</template>

<script>
import FullCalendar from '@fullcalendar/vue';
import dayGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/daygrid';
import interactionPlugin from '@fullcalendar/interaction';
import bootstrapPlugin from '@fullcalendar/bootstrap';

export default {
  components: {
    FullCalendar,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      calendarPlugins: [dayGridPlugin, interactionPlugin, bootstrapPlugin],
      calendarHeader: {
        left: 'prev today next',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'dayGridDay, dayGridWeek, dayGridMonth',
      },
    };
  },
  computed: {},
  methods: {
    onSelectDay(event) {
      console.log(event);
    },
  },
};
</script>

<style lang="stylus">
@import '~@fullcalendar/core/main.css'
@import '~@fullcalendar/daygrid/main.css'
@import '~@fullcalendar/bootstrap/main.css'
</style>
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/fullcalendar-v4-vue-ekyh3?file=/src/DemoApp.vue

[What my calendar looks like:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Buchw.png)

[Expected image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oSzfS.png)

edit: added link to expected result form docs

Comment: sorry, it's unclear what you expected it to look like, instead of your screenshot? The codesandbox demo doesn't seem to have any theme at all.

Comment: Hello, i edited the post and added an expected result image. Here is the doc. https://fullcalendar.io

Comment: Ok that's clearer. So...did you also include the main bootstrap stylesheet and the fontawesome stylesheet, as mentioned here: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/bootstrap-theme ? I can't see that from your code above.

Comment: I followed the documentation to enable bootstrap theme. The normal theme seems to be working fine (change themeSystem='standard' on the tag) edit: i posted this as you posted your comment. i was adding this to explain a bit. i have answered below.

Comment: That's not what I asked. Can you answer my specific question please. Did you include those two stylesheets in your page, or not? I mean `<link href='https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/css/all.css' rel='stylesheet'>
<link href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css' rel='stylesheet' />` as mentioned in the docs.

Comment: Bootstrap is included in as CDN and if you scroll down there is a style tag with imports for stylesheet

Comment: Are you talking about the in codesandbox? I was looking at your code in the question above, which is supposed to contain all the necessary information for studying your problem

Comment: My code above also includes it at the end, if you scroll the code down

Comment: this section ```<style lang="stylus">
@import '~@fullcalendar/core/main.css'
@import '~@fullcalendar/daygrid/main.css'
@import '~@fullcalendar/bootstrap/main.css'
</style>```

Comment: If you mean `@fullcalendar/bootstrap/main.css` then no that's not what I'm talking about. That's fullCalendar's bootstrap plugin CSS file. I'm talking about the actual base bootstrap file as mentioned in the documentation I linked you to. And the fontawesome file which is also mentioned. It's the first requirement mentioned in https://fullcalendar.io/docs/bootstrap-theme

Comment: It says _The Bootstrap stylesheet must be separately loaded in its own <link> tag. Also, a FontAwesome stylesheet must be loaded (more info). Example:_

`<link href='https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/css/all.css' rel='stylesheet'>
<link href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css' rel='stylesheet' />` . Did you load those files? It doesn't look like you did.

Comment: It doesnt work on my code but by adding it to the code box it fixes the styling.

Comment: I thought importing the css is the same as the style sheet? could you mind explaining the difference to me? Also thank you for helping debug this issue. Really appreciate your time.

Comment: Yes CSS and stylesheet are the same thing basically. In common usage, the word "stylesheet" usually means a file containing some CSS rules. CSS stands for "Cascading Style Sheets" But the important point here is that you need several different stylesheets - one comes from the makers of bootstrap, one comes from the makers of fontawesome, and one comes from the makers of fullCalendar (this is the one you had already loaded). All of the styles in those three files combine together to create the theme. You only had one of them in your page, but you needed all 3.